# error calling jquery webservice dotnetnuke

Tags: jquery, web-services, dotnetnuke

I have read a lot about jquery and i have a simple webservice that returns a method. Now i want to call that webservice with jquery in dotnetnuke but I get an error saying file not found (Error Number 404).

Here is my code:

WEBSERVICE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;


/// <summary>
/// Summary description for TestPost
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment       the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class TestPost : System.Web.Services.WebService {


public TestPost () {


    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}


[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
public Names[] GetNames()
{
    List<Names> list = new List<Names>();
    DataTable dt = DataStore.GetDataTable();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        Names _names = new Names();
        _names.FirstName = row["Name"].ToString();
        _names.Age = row["age"].ToString();
        list.Add(_names);
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}

}
public class DataStore
{
    public static DataTable GetDataTable()
{      
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Names");
    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name");
    DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Age");
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { dc1, dc2 });
    DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
    dr1[0] = "Ahmed";
    dr1[1] = "27";
    DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
    dr2[0] = "Peter";
    dr2[1] = "30";
    DataRow dr3 = dt.NewRow();
    dr3[0] = "John";
    dr3[1] = "20";
    DataRow dr4 = dt.NewRow();
    dr4[0] = "Ali";
    dr4[1] = "30";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
    dt.Rows.Add(dr2);
    dt.Rows.Add(dr3);
    dt.Rows.Add(dr4);
    return dt;
}
}


public class Names
{
private string _firstName;
private string _age;
public string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set { _firstName = value; }
}
public string Age
{
    get { return _age; }
    set { _age = value; }
}
}
```

MARKUP

```
<%@ Control language="C#" Inherits="GlobalPay.Modules.MainBoard.ViewMainBoard"     CodeFile="ViewMainBoard.ascx.cs" AutoEventWireup="true"%>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="Audit" Src="~/controls/ModuleAuditControl.ascx" %>  

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#Button1").click(function(event) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "TestPost.aspx/GetNames",
                 data: "{}",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function(msg) {
                      Success: " + msg);
                 },
                 error: function(msg) {
                      Failed: " + msg.status + ": " + msg.statusText);
                 }
             });   
        });  
    });

function AjaxSucceeded(result) {  
          result.d);
      }  
function AjaxFailed(result) {  
      result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);  
  }    


</script>


<body> 

<div id="container">
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="PractiseTextbox"></asp:TextBox>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button"/>    

<div id="footer">

</div>


</div>

</body>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Services;
using AjaxControlToolkit;


using DotNetNuke;
using DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules.Actions;
using DotNetNuke.Security;
using DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions;
using DotNetNuke.Services.Localization;


namespace GlobalPay.Modules.MainBoard
{
partial class ViewMainBoard : PortalModuleBase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestRegistration();


        //register the accordion script
        if (!DotNetNuke.UI.Utilities.ClientAPI.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(Page, "ui.core.js"))
        {
            DotNetNuke.UI.Utilities.ClientAPI.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, 
                "ui.core.js", "<script src=\"" + Request.ApplicationPath +
                "/jquery-1.4.1.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>");
        }


        ScriptManager objScriptManager;
        ServiceReference objServiceReference;


        if (DotNetNuke.Framework.AJAX.IsInstalled())
        {
            objScriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
            objServiceReference = new ServiceReference();
            objServiceReference.Path = ResolveUrl("TestPost.asmx");
            objScriptManager.Services.Add(objServiceReference);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Please review my code to see if i am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like the path to the ASMX file isn't correct (hence the 404).  Try this:

```
url: '<%=ResolveUrl("TestPost.asmx/GetNames")%>'
```

Since you're calling this from a DNN module, it's unlikely that a path relative to the current module control will get to the right place; you need the path to be relative to the page, and you won't know that at compile time.  [`ResolveUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) will give you a URL that'll work on the current page, regardless of where that is.